# How to permanently move an item from one array to another?

Tags: arrays, swift

I have a UILabel that holds strings coming from an array. When a UIButton is pressed, the first item from that array is removed and appended to an empty array depending on what the sender.currentTitle is. It works fine while using the app, but when the user goes out of the section and back in, the array starts at the original item, and the empty array is empty again, so the changes are not permanent. Any ideas as to how to make those changes permanent?

I'm not making a profitable app btw, I'm just learning to code on my free time and trying different ideas.

Code looks something like this:

```
var emptyArray = [String]()
var arrayForUILabel = ["Hello","world","!"]

@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
emptyArray.append(arrayForUILabel.remove(at: 0))
}
```

Comment: This question is to broad since there are so many options here but here is one suggestion. Learn about UserDefaults and either store the arrays themselves or some index or counter that tells how many strings that have been moved and use that to start from the same state as the app was when it was used the last time.

Comment: Cool, I'll look that up. Thanks!

Comment: you need to create global array which holds the value till user close whole app. Just read how you can achieve this

Comment: Checking. Thanks!